# d3.js force graph varying link distance

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I want to make the links between nodes vary depending on the "distance" value I put in the links. This is surprisingly difficult - I've searched around and found no satisfying solution.

This is what I have.

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { 
        return d.id;
    }).distance(function(d) { 
        return d.distance;
    }).strength(1))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

Setting the distance value to fixed variable (e.g. `distance(100)`) works, but not if I use function.

Here is the complete snippet: http://plnkr.co/edit/xAFGFpIBIRxdyb1Y?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: Link distance can certainly be set by a function, however, constraints of geometry may mean that distances are not as specified, likewise, competing forces may result in lengths that are different than specified. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38253560/7106086) help?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to your own question? I am currently having the same issue.